# How can i write a code to know the integer divisible by the second?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code

```
i = input()

w = input()

if i % w >  0 :
  
   print("Yes")
```

which takes two integers as input. If the first is exactly divisible by the second (such as 10 and 5 or 24 and 8, but not 10 and 3 or 24 and 7) it outputs “Yes”, otherwise “No”, except when the second is zero, in which case it outputs “Cannot divide by zero”. But it caused an error. Please help me know what's wrong with this code and the answer.

Comment: Whats the error? Where's the rest of your code? You only have `print("Yes")` where do you specify `print("No")`?

Answer (score 2):

Cast to integer with `int()` and group with parentheses

```
i = int(input())
w = int(input())
if (i % w) > 0:
   print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `int` to change the object type from string to integer.

To handle divide by 0 use try and except.

```
i = int(input())
w = int(input())

try:
    if (i%w) == 0:
        print("Yes")
    else:
         print("No")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("second input can't be 0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the modulus function returns zero when the number is a divisor, you don’t even have to use and `==` operator.

```
try:
    result = “Yes” if not (i % w) else “No”
except ZeroDivisionError:
    result = “Divide by zero”
print(result)
```